# Laminar downflow of liquid from a round tap

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Let's consider laminar flow of normal liquid from a tap with round opening of radius $r_0$. The liquid leaves the opening with vertical velocity $v_0$ (for simplicity, let's assume this velocity is the same across entire liquid flow at the level of the opening). Will it be correct (at least within first approximation) to consider the shape of the liquid spray to be defined by free falling of the continuous water body?

Other factors to take into account could be surface tension which tries to squeeze the liquid (thus accelerating it) and air friction which slows the flow down also causing the velocity of outer layers to smaller than the velocity of innermost layers. The following also assumes there is no rotation of the flow involved and Coriolis effect is neglected.

Is it correct to assume that if both surface tension and friction are low, the same amount of liquid $dV$ should pass through every section $S(x)$ of the flow at every time $dt$:

$$
v(x) S(x) = v_0 \pi r_0^2
$$

Here axis $X$ goes downwards along $\mathbf{g}$, and velocity $v(x)$ is determined from equation:

$$
v^2(x) - v_0^2 = 2 g x
$$

$$
v(x) = \sqrt{v_0^2 + 2gx}
$$

Finally,

$$
S(x) = \frac{v_0 \pi r_0^2}{\sqrt{v_0^2+2gx}} = \frac{\pi r_0^2}{\sqrt{1 + 2gx / v_0^2}}
$$

Is there a flaw in this consideration and is it too inaccurate?

Comment: Do you also want to include the viscous behavior of the fluid?

Comment: Including viscous behaviour makes sense along with taking air friction into account. Probably something can be devised for ideal liquid first.

Comment: Suppose you have a very highly viscous fluid like a polymer melt.  Would you know how to set up the calculation for that kind of situation; what physical factors would you include?  Do you think that axial air drag would be significant, and what about inertia?

Comment: This would be interesting, but may make the problem too complex.

Comment: How do you define too complex?  This is a routine model used in the manmade fiber production industry to analyze molten fiber spinning operations.